# Angular 2, Keycloak: securing certain routes

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have **Angular 2** application secured by **Keycloak**, done by example [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/fc6d6ff7f7dae7fb25edf052659d18cd8de55a5f/examples/demo-template/angular2-product-app).

**I wonder, how can I secure just certain routes.**

*main.ts:*

```
 KeycloakService.init()
 .then(() => {
   const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
   platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
 })
 .catch(() => window.location.reload());
```

*keycloak.service.ts:*

```
@Injectable()
export class KeycloakService {

  static auth: any = {};

  static loginUser: KeycloakUser;

  static init(): Promise<any> {

  let keycloakAuth: Keycloak.KeycloakInstance = Keycloak('keycloak/keycloak.json');

  KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = false;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
    .success(() => {
      KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn = true;
      KeycloakService.auth.authz = keycloakAuth;

      KeycloakService.auth.logoutUrl = keycloakAuth.authServerUrl + "/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=/angular2-product/index.html";
      resolve();
    })
    .error(() => {
      reject();
    });
   });
 }
 ....
```

Comment: Please improve your question. The question should contain the essential parts of the code directly instead of just a link to an external resource. What have you tried, where did you fail? What is the actual and expected behavior?  Error messages, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, hope it will be helpful for someone:

1. Remove from main.ts keycloak initialization and boostrap AppModule as usual:

   ```
   if (environment.production) {
       enableProdMode();
   }

   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
   ```
2. In **app.component.ts** add:

   ```
   import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
   ...

   constructor(private router: Router) {
     router.events.forEach(element => {
         if (element instanceof NavigationStart && 
            (element.url === '/secure-route-1' || 
             element.url === '/secure-route-2')) {

           if (!KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn) {
                KeycloakService.init()
                   .then(() => {})
                   .catch(() => window.location.reload());
              }
         }
     });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Guard for your routes, I have the next implementation:

app.routes.ts:

```
export const rs: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: PersonAppComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'other',  component: LoginComponent },
];
```

Home is a protected route, and other is of free access.

auth-guard.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate,OnInit {

  constructor(private ck: KeycloakService) {
    console.log("INIT AuthGuard: " + KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn )
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  canActivate() {
    console.log("check guard: " + KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn)
    return KeycloakService.auth.loggedIn;
  }

}
```

My main.ts is similar.

I hope to be helpful.